# Plotting matplotlib figure through a class doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, class, matplotlib

I created a class "Plot" for matplotlib plot objects. Running the following code neither shows error nor outputs anything. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Plot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot()
    def create_plot_background(self):
        self.ax.set_xlabel('X')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Y')

x, y = [range(10), range(10)]

p = Plot()

p.create_plot_background()
p.ax.plot(x, y)
p.fig.show()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce when substituting `p.fig.show()` (fig.show() doesn't work in my environment) with `plt.show()`. Depending on your intentions, you may also be interested in [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#runtime-rc-settings) to set figure properties consistently.

Comment: @Mr.T What can I do differently to display the intended plot? I have to do this using Plot class as defined.

Comment: @Mr.T I am using python 3.8

Comment: I just told you - use `plt.show()`. The behavior of `p.fig.show()` depends on the backend and operating system (in my environment the figure is closed immediately), but `plt.show()` should have consistent behavior.